# When setting item to DONE, how do I automatically change following item to NEXTACTION?

Tags: org-mode

So I, like many others, use org-mode to implement GTD to manage my life. One thing that happens since I'm in school is long-term projects, which have milestones. In and of themselves these milestones are strictly sequential events, and within these milestones even usually there are strictly sequential events.

As it stands now, I mark all the items that are blocked because of the current `NEXTACTION` as `TODO`. Whenever I finish a task and mark it `DONE`, I have the mental burden of then reviewing my project support materials to determine what becomes the new `NEXTACTION`. This is fine, but inefficient if I already *know* the order of events. Is there a way to automatically change the next item down (in a list, actual next line, any way) to `NEXTACTION` when I mark an item `DONE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [org-depend](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-depend.html) (from the `org-plus-contrib` package) to do exactly this.  Make sure it's loaded by adding `(add-to-list 'org-modules 'org-depend)` to your init file.  Then just set the `TRIGGER` property to `chain-siblings(NEXTACTION)`.  When this entry is marked done, the next sibling will be set to `NEXTACTION` *and* it gets the same `TRIGGER` property, so you can continue the chain.  More complex methods for selecting the "next" item are possible.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!